# Where should my beamer theme be located?

Tags: beamer, themes, folders

I recently downloaded a beamer theme: {metro}

I made a beamer by
1. Create folder 'presentation'
2. Copy beamer theme in 'presentation'
3. Create tex file in 'presentation'

This works fine.

However, I don't want to copy the beamer theme to folders everytime I create new a beamer presentation.

I think there is some folder which contains the default beamer themes.

Where should I place my beamer theme to use it by just typing \usetheme{metro} instead of copying the theme in the same folder?

Comment: Are you on Linux or on Windows?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te